# Bind json to html table in view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

i am trying to bind my data to a html table in my view, how do i go about this

```
public ActionResult FlugTopAir()
     {
         DataModel db = new DataModel();
         var test = db.Database.SqlQuery<FlugTopAirData>("exec sp_FlugTopAir").ToList();
         return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

     }

     public class FlugTopAirData
     {
         public string Airline { get; set; }
         public double Spend { get; set; }
         public double TA { get; set; }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on the client side framework that you use.
If you are looking for the native js here is the link:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_html.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery Ajax to call that controller action. Like below

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Airline</td>
            <td>Spend</td>
            <td>TA</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
</table>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("FlugTopAir")',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var rows = result.map(function (record) {
                var row = $("<tr></tr>");
                var airline = $("<td></td>").html(record.Airline);
                var spend = $("<td></td>").html(record.Spend);
                var ta = $("<td></td>").html(record.TA);

                row.append(airline, spend, ta);

                return row;
            });

            $("#tableBody").append(rows);
        }
    });
    </script>
}
```

You should probably consider using some template engine like [JSRender](https://www.jsviews.com/) for this to be honest.

Or the easiest way would be to return the view with model so you can use Razor syntax to iterate through Model from the view

View (Index.cshtml)

```
@using MVCTestApp.Models

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Airline
        <td>Spend</td>
        <td>TA</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (TestModel testModel in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@testModel.Airline</td>
        <td>@testModel.Spend</td>
        <td>@testModel.TA</td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

In controller, instead of returning Json, return View

```
return View(test);
```